# Диаграмма классов получения метаданных об отчетах

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, инспекция-кода, solid

На файловой системе хранятся отчеты школ. Есть отчеты **персональные** – персональные для каждой школы (класс `School`). И есть отчеты **общие** – отчеты, которые содержат общую информацию/статистику по школам региона.

Метаданные (информация об отчетах) хранится в классе `ReportMeta` и они одинаковы, как для персональных, так и для общих отчетов:

```
public class ReportMeta
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
    public string OnlineLink { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

Алгоритмы получения `ReportMeta` для персональных и общих отчетов **разные**. Причем код получения `ReportMeta` для персональных постоянен, а вот код для общих отчетов в будущем может претерпеть изменения, т.к. структура хранение этих (общих отчетов) будет иная и еще планируется добавить другие типы отчетов. Поэтому я сделал разъединения:

```
public interface IReportMeta
{
    IEnumerable<ReportMeta> GetReportMetas();
}

public class PrivateReportMeta : IReportMeta
{
    private School school;
    public PrivateReportMeta(School school)
    {
        this.school = school;
    }
    public IEnumerable<ReportMeta> GetReportMetas()
    {
        //…
        return new List<ReportMeta>();
    }

}

public class PublicReportMeta : IReportMeta
{
    public IEnumerable<ReportMeta> GetReportMetas()
    {
        //...
        return new List<ReportMeta>();
    }
}
```

Клиентскому коду необходимо получить списки `ReportMeta` в общей куче и поэтому предполагается следующее:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    School currentSchool = new School();
    IReportMeta privateReportMetas = new PrivateReportMeta(currentSchool);
    IReportMeta publicReportMetas = new PublicReportMeta();
    var allReportMetas = privateReportMetas.GetReportMetas().Union(publicReportMetas.GetReportMetas());
    //...
}
```

**Вопрос**

1. Соблюдены ли в коде принципы SOLID?
2. Есть ли **грубое** нарушение в проектировании приложения?

Буду благодарен за предложение другой архитектуры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Принципы SOLID это всего лишь рекомендации. На мой взгляд, с этим все у вас в порядке.
2. Во-первых, Union делает не то, что вам надо, используйте Concat. Во вторых, чтобы избавится от большого количества `new ...ReportMeta`, можно применить паттерн Factory.  Это актуально, если у вас будет много видов отчетов. Для двух, думаю и так нормально.

Comment: _можно применить паттерн Factory_. А про какой паттерн конкретно идет речь - `Abstract Factory` или `Factory Method`?

Comment: @adamshakhabov Либо обычную `Factory`, либо `Factory Method`. Про разницу можно почитать [тут](http://cpp-reference.ru/patterns/creational-patterns/), правда на C++